# How to write an eBPF program for a customer kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf, bcc-bpf

I would like to be able to write eBPF programs for my customer kernel.

The problem is when I modify the kernel and add trace points for example, I won't be able to install bpfcc-tools package because they do not have that package built for my custom kernel.

So, I would like to find a way to write these programs without depending on pre-built packages.

Comment: I don't see many options except compiling BCC yourself. Have you tried that? Seems pretty straightforward from [their instructions](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

Comment: I am trying to install clang now to be able to build bcc, but the dependencies are a hell.

Comment: right... last time I had to do that I just compiled clang from source too :')

Comment: Why do you want to use bcc? Couldn't you just use libbpf? That may be easier as you can compile your BPF programs on some other machine and load them with libbpf on the custom-kernel machine.